# Rails 3 scope with multiple models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, scope

Here are my models:

Patient:

```
has_many :patient_records
```

PatientRecord:

```
belongs_to :patient
has_many :progress_reports
```

ProgressReport:

```
has_one :patient_record
```

The query I am trying to produce is to get all patients where progress_reports are older than or equal to 7 days from now (using a date_of_report column in progress_reports) while including or joining the patient record table... I have been working on this for so long that I have ran into a brick wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
scope :recent_patients, lambda 
{ |since_when| join(:progress_reports)
  .where("progress_reports.created_at >= ?", since_when)}
```

in your `Patient` model

Comment: Thanks for your help over the past couple of days!

Answer (score 0):

```
reports = ProgressReport.where(:created_at > 7.days.ago).all
```

if you want to get each patient that belongs to each record, do:

```
reports.each do |r|
   puts r.patient.name
end
```